# Why objc_class has different definition between runtime.h and objc-runtime-new.h

Tags: objective-c, runtime

My puzzle is how the compiler can compile those two same name struct.

objc_class definition in "objc/runtime.h" which open to developers

```
struct objc_class {
    Class _Nonnull isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;

#if !__OBJC2__
    Class _Nullable super_class                              OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    const char * _Nonnull name                               OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_ivar_list * _Nullable ivars                  OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_method_list * _Nullable * _Nullable methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_cache * _Nonnull cache                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_protocol_list * _Nullable protocols          OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
/* Use `Class` instead of `struct objc_class *` */
```

but the project headers file "objc-runtime-new.h" has different definition(member variables and functions).

```
struct objc_class : objc_object {
    // Class ISA;
    Class superclass;
    cache_t cache;             // formerly cache pointer and vtable
    // class_data_bits_t 
    class_data_bits_t bits;    // class_rw_t * plus custom rr/alloc flags

    class_rw_t *data() {

        return bits.data();
    }
    void setData(class_rw_t *newData) {
        bits.setData(newData);
    }

    …

    …

};
```

I do not understand how those two structs converted.

Comment: I am not sure anybody can answer this question without reading your mind. Can you elaborate with details assuming we don't know anything about the problem?

Comment: @SteveFriedl I add some description.The code above is Apple open-source code,i have no idea about same name struct in same project which have different structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is what you see when using the runtime from your code.  The other is what the runtime uses internally as an implementation detail.

Note that in both cases the first slot is the `isa` (though the `objc-runtime-new.h` effectively inherits that slot from `objc_object`) and the second slot is the `superclass`.

Those are the only two slots accessible from outside the runtime.   Internally to the runtime, the struct has more entries for the rest of the metadata associated with the class.

Comment: thanks.Is it mean that runtime project include objc-runtime-new.h only and developer can include runtime.h only,so it's not exist redefination error?

Comment: @apricot Most likely.  I haven't looked at how the runtime is built in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

There is "#if !OBJC_TYPES_DEFINED" at top of "objc/runtime.h" file.And "OBJC_TYPES_DEFINED" is defined in "objc-private.h".So objc_class definition in "objc/runtime.h" is not used.